# Show this subpace of a Hilbert space is dense

Tags: hilbert-spaces

This is part of an exercise in Rudin's Functional Analysis, in the chapter on Unbounded Operators. Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$. Let $X$ be the set of all finite sums $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \alpha_ie_i$ where $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\alpha_i=0$. The exercise is to prove that $X$ is dense in $H$. Since $\{e_i\}$ is an onb, it is clear that every $x\in H$ is a limit of finite sums of the form $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \alpha_ie_i$, but how do we ensure that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \alpha_i=0$?

Comment: Hint: try to approximate the base vectors $e_k.$

Comment: Alternatively: try to compute $X^\perp.$

Comment: Thank you, the second hint worked perfectly!

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk you should post this as hint-like answer

Comment: @Norbert: ok, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** try to compute $X^\perp.$